# A parametrix construction for heat boundary value problem using Fourier transformation

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, parabolic-pde

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth bounded open subset in $\mathcal{R}^{d}$, with $d \geqslant 3
 $ and $T>0$. Consider the linear parabolic initial Dirichlet boundary value problem with $f\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ or $L^2(\Omega)$ and $g\in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\tag{Heat}
\partial_t v - \Delta v = f \quad  &\text{in } (0,T)\times\Omega,\\
v(0,.) =0 \quad  &\text{on }    \Omega.\\
v =g \quad  &\text{on }   (0,T)\times\partial \Omega.\\
\end{cases}
 \end{align}
I am basically looking for a reference where I can find a construction of a parametrix for the above problem using Fourier transformation. Thanks in advance to anyone who could offer help.